# If $a_n \neq 0$ for all natural numbers n , $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n $ converges $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n/b_n =1\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} b_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $a_n \neq 0$ for all natural numbers $n$ , $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n $ converges $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} =1 $ then $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} b_n$ converges

I am trying to find counterexamples to this proposition but I'm unable to do so, is it likely that it is true? Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I am trying to find counterexamples", but either give your working or explain why your idea did not work. Explaining why you thought a counterexample exists would also help. (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 6):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt n$, so $\sum_na_n$ is a convergent alternating series. Let $b_n=a_n$ for odd $n$ but $b_n=a_n+(1/n)$ for even $n$. Then the partial sums of $\sum_nb_n$ exceed those of $\sum_na_n$ by partial sums of the (positive, harmonic) series $\sum_k\frac1{2k}$, which diverges. So $\sum_nb_n$ diverges.The ratios $a_n/b_n$ of corresponding terms are $1$ for odd $n$ and
$$
\frac{1/\sqrt n}{(1/\sqrt n)+(1/n)}=\frac1{1+(1/\sqrt n)}
$$
for even $n$.  So $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/b_n=1$.

Historical remark: Cauchy claimed the statement in the title is true, but then Dirichlet found a counterexample. In this connection, Dirichlet was the first to point out the importance of distinguishing absolute convergence from conditional convergence, even before its relevance to rearranging the terms of the series was recognized.

Comment: +1 On the answer and historical remark!